# How to shift specific cells using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

My excel sheet contains different regions on the same sheet like:

```
region1:                region2:       
John       2            A         1  
John       1            B         2  
Sue        1            C         3  
Sue        2            D         4  
Alice      5            E         5  
Bob        1            F         6
```

I want to add new items into one of these regions without affecting the other regions.   I tried using `rowShift()` method but it is also deleting the complete rows. Is there any way that can shift the specific cells down and can insert rows into the specific regions like this:   In my given example I want to add one more row in region1 (also retaining all old rows) and it will become:

```
region1:                region2:       
newval     newval       A         1  
John       2            B         2  
John       1            C         3  
Sue        1            D         4  
Sue        2            E         5  
Alice      5            F         6
Bob        1
```

Comment: The example you've shown is only replacing cells *John 2* with *newval newval*, it does not shift anything down. is that what you want?

Comment: By mistake i could not write the full rows. Please read the line (also retaining all old values). I do not need to replace , want to add.

Comment: is there no one has any idea :(

Comment: probably you have to shift down the row and then duplicate the cells you want

Answer (score 3):

If the above issue still persisting, I can give you a method for the same.

```
public static void shiftCells(int startCellNo, int endCellNo, int shiftRowsBy, Sheet sheet){

    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println(lastRowNum); //=7
    //      int rowNumAfterAdding = lastRowNum+shiftRowsBy;
    for(int rowNum=lastRowNum;rowNum>0;rowNum--){
        Row rowNew;
        if(sheet.getRow((int)rowNum+shiftRowsBy)==null){
            rowNew = sheet.createRow((int)rowNum+shiftRowsBy);
        }
        rowNew = sheet.getRow((int)rowNum+shiftRowsBy);
        Row rowOld = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        System.out.println("RowNew is "+rowNum+" and Row Old is "+(int)(rowNum+shiftRowsBy));
        System.out.println("startCellNo = "+startCellNo+" endCellNo = "+endCellNo+" shiftRowBy = "+shiftRowsBy);
        for(int cellNo=startCellNo; cellNo<=endCellNo;cellNo++){
            rowNew.createCell(cellNo).setCellValue(rowOld.getCell(cellNo).getStringCellValue().toString());
            rowOld.getCell(cellNo).setCellValue("");
            System.out.println("working on " +cellNo);
        }
    }       
}
```